# How to hook into Wordpress's image and thumbnails saving?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a function e.g. OptimizeImage($path) and basically it will compress the image given. So I want this function to be invoked when post attachment is saved and corresponding thumbnails are generated. What are the names of hooks?

Answer (score 1):

You can add action to `'add_attachment'`

This hook is called when an attachment created by wp_insert_attachment() in wp-includes/post.php.

Comment: how about thumbnails?